# How to animate moving image from center of one imageView to another? (Swift)

Tags: swift, uiimageview

How do you animate moving image from one UIIMageView to another UIImageView?

Comment: If you are using Auto Layout then you can define constraints on `UIImageVIew` ...You can refer to this video https://youtu.be/d1e9bKtOEH8

Comment: Do you want the image to appear to move from the first image view to the second, and replace the image in the other image view? What should happen to the image in the first image view? What sort of transition do you want to have happen when the image arrives at the destination location? Should the old image disappear at the instant the new image arrives at it's final location?

Comment: @DuncanC : Yes. I want the image to appear to move from the first image view to the second and then replace the image of second one with the first one and hide the first imageView.

Comment: See Kstin's answer as a start then. It doesn't deal with AutoLayout constraints, so it may not work in all situations, but it should give you the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let center = imgView1.center
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
      self.imgView1.center = self.imgView2.center
}) { _ in
      self.imgView2.image = self.imgView1.image
      self.imgView1.image = nil
      self.imgView1.center = center
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Although it didn't solve my issue, it helped me with the implementation. I used core animations and CGAffineTransform(translationX:x, y:y) for animation and used center.x, center.y.